# Button jumps position when app enters background

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I have a small button to show and hide a UI element. When I press the home button to leave the app and then go back to it, the button jumps to its original position, not the new position that it was animated too.

The desired action is that it would remain in the position the user left it in when they leave and come back to the app.

[image: This before the button is pressed]

[image: This is after]

[image: If I send the app to the background it comes back like this.]

```
@IBAction func hideChartTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let delay = 0.3
    if chart.isHidden {
        self.chart.isHidden = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: delay, animations: {
            self.hideChart.center.y = (self.hideChart.center.y - self.chart.bounds.height)
            self.chart.center.y = (self.chart.center.y - self.chart.bounds.height)
        }, completion: nil)
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: delay, animations: {
            self.hideChart.center.y = (self.hideChart.center.y + self.chart.bounds.height)
            self.chart.center.y = (self.chart.center.y + self.chart.bounds.height)
            self.hideChart.setNeedsDisplay()
        }, completion: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: {
            self.chart.isHidden = true
        })
    }
}
```

That is the code I use to hide and show the chart and move the button. The default position for the button and chart are set in the main.Storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I wasn't updating the constraints as well. I'm still animating the centre movement but after the animation, I'm resetting the constraints like this:

```
@IBAction func hideChartTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let delay = 0.3
    if chart.isHidden {
        self.chart.isHidden = false
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: delay, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
            self.hideChart.center.y = (self.hideChart.center.y - self.chart.bounds.height)
            self.chart.center.y = (self.chart.center.y - self.chart.bounds.height)
        }, completion: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: {
            self.hideChartBottomConstraint.constant = 0
            self.hideChart.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    } else {
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: delay, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
            self.hideChart.center.y = (self.hideChart.center.y + self.chart.bounds.height)
            self.chart.center.y = (self.chart.center.y + self.chart.bounds.height)
        }, completion: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: {
            self.hideChartBottomConstraint.constant = self.chart.bounds.height
            self.hideChart.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.chart.isHidden = true
        })
    }
}
```